# Slideshow of images where each post has a certain number of images retrieved from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, css

I used two tables the first one contains information about the post & the second has images. So, when the user posts on my site the information is stored in the 1st table & images in the 2nd table which is linked with the 1st table in 1st table ID:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO hommes (user, tel, categories, modele, taille, 
 couleur, img, date, prix)"."VALUES('$usr', '$tel', '$CATEG', '$MODELE', 
 '$TAILLE', '$COULEUR', '$fileName', '$date', '$prix')";
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  header("location: vetement.php");
  //echo "New record created successfully";

    }
```

then the main page contain all postes of all users :

```
    $sql = "SELECT hommes.id, hommes.user,hommes.tel, hommes.date, 
    hommes.categories, hommes.modele, hommes.taille, hommes.couleur, 
  hommes.prix, userfiles.FileName, userfiles.FilePath,
      GROUP_CONCAT(userfiles.FileName) as FileName
   FROM hommes
  LEFT JOIN userfiles ON hommes.id=userfiles.parent_id
  WHERE hommes.id=userfiles.parent_id AND active = 1
  GROUP BY hommes.id DESC";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  foreach( explode(',', $row['FileName']) as $img )
  echo "<img src='uploads/".$img."'>";
    }
```

I want to do a slideshow for each echo. I tried many ways but I couldn't fix this.

NB: "each echo has a deferent number of images"

Comment: [Try this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

Comment: it just play the slideshow for the first post !

Comment: no answer !! no help !!